# Approaches on fixing the Ambiguity

Tags: c++, overloading, implicit-conversion, ambiguity

I have been asked the following example to fix without modifying both function declaration and call.

```
void Display(int *nData)
{
}

void Display(float *fData)
{
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    float b = 4.0f;

    Display(&a);
    Display(&b);
    Display(nullptr or NULL); // Ambiguity here, as nullptr or NULL (0) can be converted implicitly by compiler to both int and float

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas ? 
Thanks

EDIT: Thanks for answers to fix this using std::nullptr_t with an overload, but what if the argument is "NULL" instead of nullptr ? How to fix that ?

Comment: Can you add an overload of the function ?

Comment: Why would passing in `nullptr` here have any meaning? Defining your functions as `float&` and `int&` could avoid this, but if that's off the table that's harsh. You could call this failure a feature and be done with it.

Comment: @tadman I know we can fix that using reference, but I was asked by some one whether it is possible or not.

Comment: @nefas Yes, we can add overload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be fixed by adding a "dummy" overload taking a [`std::nullptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) argument:

```
void Display(std::nullptr_t)
{
}
```

This will then be called when passing `nullptr`.

---

The macro `NULL` and the previous recommended null-pointer `0` are problematic though, as they will again introduce ambiguity.

Solving for `0` is easy, just add *another* overload taking a simple `int` (not a pointer) as argument. This *might* also solve the ambiguity with `NULL` but also might not.

The problem with [the `NULL` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) is that it's implementation defined. It *might* be expanded as `nullptr`. It *might* be expanded as `0`. Or it *might* be expanded to some other integer literal which evaluates as zero, but of an unknown type.

For example on my current system `NULL` is defined as `0LL`, that is a `long long int`.

To handle all *currently* possible null pointers you need the following overloads:

```
void Display(std::nullptr_t);  // For nullptr
void Display(int);             // For 0 and some implementations of NULL
void Display(long);            // For some implementations of NULL
void Display(long long);       // For some implementations of NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if parameter is "NULL" instead of nullptr ?

Comment: @DineshG Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`nullptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) with another overload:

```
void Display(std::nullptr_t nullData)
{
    // Handle special case of nullptr
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if parameter is "NULL" instead of nullptr ?